# How to get prices from html by python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to web scrape The North Face, I managed to get the title, description, color, ecc. But seems to hard for me to get the prices. How can i get the price of a product?

I tried something like selenium but didnt work, I got an empty string. Someone know how can I do this stuff?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs



r = requests.get("https://www.thenorthface.it/shop/it/tnf-it/berretto-jim-a5wh?variationId=KS7")
contenuto = bs(r.text, "html.parser")



title = contenuto.find(class_='product-content-info-name product-info-js').text.strip()
print(title)

descrizione = contenuto.find(class_='desc-container pdp-details-desc-container').text.strip()
print(descrizione)

caratteristiche = contenuto.find(class_='inner-content product-details-section-inner-content pdp-features-inner-content').text.strip()
print(caratteristiche)

colore = contenuto.find(class_='product-content-form-attr-selected attr-selected attribute-label-value attribute-label-value-js').text.strip()
print(colore)

prezzo= contenuto.find(class_='product-price price')
print(prezzo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Main issue here is that the content is provided dynamically by `JavaScript` as one of the class names hints.

So there are various ways to get a price, depending on what is needed exactly:

1. Check the static content of `meta`:

   ```
   contenuto.select_one('[property="og:price:amount"]').get('content')
   ```
2. Check the static price section :

   ```
   contenuto.select_one('[itemprop="price"]').get('content')
   ```
3. Check meta again and request the actually price for specific store via ajax price url:

   ```
   contenuto.select_one('[property="og:price:url"]').get('content')
   ```
4. Check the `JavaScript` variables and extract the price from there:

   ```
   var itemPrices = {"1267185":{"pricing":{"productId":"1267185","default":{"lowPrice":"€ 112,00","lowPriceNumeric":112,"highPrice":"€ 160,00","highPriceNumeric":160,"lowListPrice":"€ 160,00","lowListPriceNumeric":160,"highListPrice":"€ 160,00","highListPriceNumeric":160},"7741124012283612344":{"8W8":{"highPrice":"€ 160,00","highPriceNumeric":160,"lowPrice":"€ 160,00","lowPriceNumeric":160,"highListPrice":"€ 160,00","highListPriceNumeric":160,"lowListPrice":"€ 160,00","lowListPriceNumeric":160,"sku":[1295427,1295426,1295430,1295429,1295428]},"43M":{"highPrice":"€ 160,00","highPriceNumeric":160,"lowPrice":"€ 160,00","lowPriceNumeric":160,"highListPrice":"€ 160,00","highListPriceNumeric":160,"lowListPrice":"€ 160,00","lowListPriceNumeric":160,"sku":[1267195,1267199,1267198,1267197,1267196]},"5R7":{"highPrice":"€ 112,00","highPriceNumeric":112,"lowPrice":"€ 112,00","lowPriceNumeric":112,"highListPrice":"€ 160,00","highListPriceNumeric":160,"lowListPrice":"€ 160,00","lowListPriceNumeric":160,"sku":[1267203,1267202,1267201,1267200,1267204]}},"7741124012283612349":{"XL":{"highPrice":"€ 160,00","highPriceNumeric":160,"lowPrice":"€ 112,00","lowPriceNumeric":112,"highListPrice":"€ 160,00","highListPriceNumeric":160,"lowListPrice":"€ 160,00","lowListPriceNumeric":160,"sku":[1267203,1295429,1267198]},"L":{"highPrice":"€ 160,00","highPriceNumeric":160,"lowPrice":"€ 112,00","lowPriceNumeric":112,"highListPrice":"€ 160,00","highListPriceNumeric":160,"lowListPrice":"€ 160,00","lowListPriceNumeric":160,"sku":[1295426,1267200,1267195]},"XS":{"highPrice":"€ 160,00","highPriceNumeric":160,"lowPrice":"€ 112,00","lowPriceNumeric":112,"highListPrice":"€ 160,00","highListPriceNumeric":160,"lowListPrice":"€ 160,00","lowListPriceNumeric":160,"sku":[1295430,1267204,1267199]},"S":{"highPrice":"€ 160,00","highPriceNumeric":160,"lowPrice":"€ 112,00","lowPriceNumeric":112,"highListPrice":"€ 160,00","highListPriceNumeric":160,"lowListPrice":"€ 160,00","lowListPriceNumeric":160,"sku":[1267202,1295428,1267197]},"M":{"highPrice":"€ 160,00","highPriceNumeric":160,"lowPrice":"€ 112,00","lowPriceNumeric":112,"highListPrice":"€ 160,00","highListPriceNumeric":160,"lowListPrice":"€ 160,00","lowListPriceNumeric":160,"sku":[1295427,1267201,1267196]}},"sku":{"1295428":{"listPrice":"€ 160,00","listPriceNumeric":160,"price":"€ 160,00","priceNumeric":160},"1295427":{"listPrice":"€ 160,00","listPriceNumeric":160,"price":"€ 160,00","priceNumeric":160},"1295426":{"listPrice":"€ 160,00","listPriceNumeric":160,"price":"€ 160,00","priceNumeric":160},"1267204":{"listPrice":"€ 160,00","listPriceNumeric":160,"price":"€ 112,00","priceNumeric":112},"1267203":{"listPrice":"€ 160,00","listPriceNumeric":160,"price":"€ 112,00","priceNumeric":112},"1267202":{"listPrice":"€ 160,00","listPriceNumeric":160,"price":"€ 112,00","priceNumeric":112},"1267201":{"listPrice":"€ 160,00","listPriceNumeric":160,"price":"€ 112,00","priceNumeric":112},"1267200":{"listPrice":"€ 160,00","listPriceNumeric":160,"price":"€ 112,00","priceNumeric":112},"1267199":{"listPrice":"€ 160,00","listPriceNumeric":160,"price":"€ 160,00","priceNumeric":160},"1267198":{"listPrice":"€ 160,00","listPriceNumeric":160,"price":"€ 160,00","priceNumeric":160},"1267197":{"listPrice":"€ 160,00","listPriceNumeric":160,"price":"€ 160,00","priceNumeric":160},"1267196":{"listPrice":"€ 160,00","listPriceNumeric":160,"price":"€ 160,00","priceNumeric":160},"1267195":{"listPrice":"€ 160,00","listPriceNumeric":160,"price":"€ 160,00","priceNumeric":160},"1295430":{"listPrice":"€ 160,00","listPriceNumeric":160,"price":"€ 160,00","priceNumeric":160},"1295429":{"listPrice":"€ 160,00","listPriceNumeric":160,"price":"€ 160,00","priceNumeric":160}}}}};
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I was always doing it with "for" loop. So it looks like this:

```
for i in contenuto.find_all("span", class_="product-content-info-name product-info-js"):
     title=i.get_text()
```

And it is working. Try it and give me feedback.

Comment: The problem is not about the name, i found the name (title) is the price (prezzo) that is not working